# Grunt Task that copies XML data into HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs

I have XML file that has some HTML data in it, I am looking to create a GRUNT script that finds < content > tag and then takes what is in the CDATA tag and puts in a blank HTML file. Would this even be possible with Grunt? (The goal is to use a grunt HTML validator npm script once it is in a HTML file to validate the HTML that was originally in the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<page>
  <title>Title Here</title>
  <content>
    <![CDATA[<div> ... </div>]]>>
  </content>
</page>
```